# Не удается авторизоваться в mysql бд, через C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Учусь взаимодействию C#(WinForms) с MySql, в интернете увидел пример кода для авторизации, который по сути переписал точь-в-точь:

```
  private void EntButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String LoginData = logField.Text;
       String PassData = passField.Text;

        DB db = new DB();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `anothertable` WHERE 'login' = @uL AND 'pass' = @uP", db.getConnection());
        command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoginData;
        command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PassData;


        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You`re in");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Get out");
    }
```

Какие бы данные ни вводил, все равно выводит "Get out". 
Вот пример кода из класса DB:

```
 class DB
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=mydatabase");

    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {


        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

При использовании Breakpoint-ов, я увидел, что table.Rows.Count всегда равен нулю.

Comment: Смотрим, какая [строка должна быть](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) и потом смотрим на вашу.

Comment: В одинарных кавычках задаются строковые литералы. Имена колонок - login, pass - нужно задавать в обратных кавычках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одинарных кавычках задаются строковые литералы. Имена колонок - login, pass - нужно задавать в обратных кавычках.